# PHP run once and insert sql twice

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, forms

My code is meant to take in a brief text and title from users and it is adding them into the database twice and can't understand why.

```
   <?php ("session.php"); ?>
    <?php require_once("connect.php"); ?>
    <?php include("header.php"); ?>             

    <?php 


        //if the submit button is pressed then the INSERT SQL statement is submitted to database
        //if (isset($_POST['testimonial_title']) && isset($_SESSION['testimonial_text'])) {

        if(isset($_POST["submit_button"])){



            $title=$_POST["testimonial_title"];
            $text=$_POST["testimonial_text"];



            //create the sql statement 
            $sql=
                "INSERT INTO testimonials 
                (testimonial_title, testimonial_text, student_ID)
                VALUES(
                '$title',
                '$text',
                1);"; //for simplicity the student_ID is kept the same


            $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
            if(!mysqli_query($con, $sql))
            {
                echo "Journal entry was not entered successfully";
            }
            else{
                echo "Journal entry was entered successfully";
            }

             mysqli_close($con);
        }

    ?>


    <html>
        <body>

        <!-- Page Content -->
                    <h1 class="page-header">Learning Journals
                        <small>- Admin</small>
                    </h1>

                    <h3>Update Learning Journals Plans</h3>

                    <form name="membership_form" action= "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" id="contactForm"  method="post">

                        <label>Learning Journals Title:</label>
                        <br>
                            <input type="text" name="testimonial_title">
                        <br>

                            <label>Learning Journal:</label>
                            <br>
                            <textarea rows="10" cols="100" name="testimonial_text" maxlength="999" style="resize:none"></textarea>
                            <br>
                        <button type="submit" name ="submit_button" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                    </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

What should happen is:

User enters title "xyz"

User enters text "xyz"

Database takes in:

```
ID | title | text | student_ID| 

1  | xyz   | xyz  | 1         |
```

But instead it the database looks like this:

```
ID | title | text | student_ID| 

1  | xyz   | xyz  | 1         | 

2  | xyz   | xyz  | 1         |
```

Comment: This isn't your answer, but I would recommend adding constraints to your table like `alter table testimonials add constraint uc_testimonials unique (title,text,studentid)` or `(title,studentid)`

Answer (score 5):

Change:

```
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        if(!mysqli_query($con, $sql))
```

To:

```
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        if(!$result)
```